# Check if string contain standalone 'c++' with regex

Tags: python, regex

So I am trying to find out if string contains standalone `'c++'` substring, for example:

`'abcabcabc c++ abc abc'` should return true

but

`'abcabcabc c++11 abc abc'` should return false.

I am trying to achieve it using this regex: `r'\bc\+\+\b'` which works fine for exactly same scenario for `'foo'` substring instead of `'c++'`
(`r'\bfoo\b'`, it returns true for `'abc abc foo abc abc'` and false for `'abc abc foo12 abc abc'`) but it does not work for `'c++'`. :(

What am I missing?

I am using python's `re` module for that, regex101.com yields the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to avoid a match if it's followed by a word character:

```
\bc\+\+(?!\w)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/d3VHyH/1

Comment: yeah, thats gonna do it for me